# i have Error when call method

Tags: java, error-handling

I write `recursive` method that has one a charachter
and  I want call method pattern in method `FCITpattern`
but when print line I have error

```
public static void FCITpattern(Scanner input, PrintWriter output, char n) {
  // Scan the int from the input file
  int c = input.nextInt();

  //output.println("FCITmath:");
  System.out.println("FCITpattern:");
  System.out.println(pattern(output, n));//this line causes the error.

  // Finally, print the result:

  output.println();
}

public static void pattern(PrintWriter output, char n) {
    if (n == 'A') {
      output.print(n);
    } else {
        char pattern = (char)((int) n - 1);
        pattern(output,pattern);
        output.print(n);
        pattern(output,pattern);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code sensibly if you are asking people to try and understand it.

Comment: One more comment: `char pattern = (char)((int) n - 1);` This line has unnecessary explicit casts. Whenever you use a binary operator (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`) in conjunction with types smaller than `int`, they will be casted to `int` implicitly. The given line can be shortened to `char pattern = (char)(n - 1);`.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` expects a String to print. However `pattern` method return type is `void`.

You should change the return type to `String` and return the `String` you wish to print.

Answer (score 0):

the compiler tells you what the error is - so its simple to understand i guess. You want to print out a method result, but your method is void and therefore does not return anything